# Identifying an older TV show/movie based on audio; looking outside into fog

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking to identify a movie or tv show based on a few lines of dialogue captured from a song. It's not much, I know, but the dialogue sounds like it's describing a fairly pivotal plot point, so hopefully that helps. The audio can be heard on this song:

(Audio sample occurs in the first minute, then again from about 4:10 to 5 mins, and again from about 6:25 to 7:10, though this last section is hard to make out)

Here's what I've gotten from the audio:

> I wasn't watching outside, as a result I unknowingly entered the fog bank. It was like nothing I'd ever seen before - it seemed to be a colloidal substance, a gluey mass. All the windows were coated. The fog reduced the lift to the rotor blades. Once more I began to slowly lose altitude. I couldn't see the sun, where I supposed it would be.
>
> I turned back to my controls for a moment. When I looked out again I saw below me a kind of garden. Well I could see vegetation and plants, but this colloidal substance (unknown) trees, and everything seemed to be in miniature. They were made of some sort of plastic material… all of a sudden cracks started to appear.
> I emerged about an hour later from *indecipherable*… at that moment, I observed phenomenal changes… *indecipherable*"

I believe it to be from a movie or tv show in the black and white era, given the quality of the audio and tenor of the man speaking, but that could be just conjecture. Any help would be appreciated - I've been looking for this for at least 3 years now with no success.

Comment: It's also quite possible it's from old time radio, too. but I've listened to most episodes of almost all the surviving old time radio SF anthologies and don't remember that as a plot point.

Comment: [This page](http://telcontar.net/Misc/samplesources.php) says that samples in that song might have been taken from [Solaris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_(2002_film)), but doesn't list which samples. There were two earlier versions of the same film.

Comment: I have one of the early versions of Solaris, but haven't had time to watch it yet.  Maybe this will give me a good reason to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to be a sample from the English dub of the 1972 Tarkovsky version of the film [Solaris.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solaris_(1972_film))

You can view the subtitles [here](http://www.divxmoviesenglishsubtitles.com/S/Solaris_(Tarkovsky)_CD1.html)

> All my efforts were required in operating the ship
>
> I wasn't watching outside.
>
> As a result, l entered the fog bank.   Was that an ordinary fog?
>
> lt was like nothing l'd ever seen before.
>
> lt seemed to be a colloidal substance, a gluey mass.
>
> All the windows were coated.
>
> Because ofthe fog's resistance l began to lose altitude.
>
> Where l supposed the sun would be, the fog glowed like fire.
>
> Half an hour later, l emerged into a large open space.

The film is available online [here](http://vimeo.com/92828882) but only in the original Russian (the sample in question is based on the speech at 13:03 when Burton speaks to the Russian Congress) but you can select the Closed Caption subtitles in English.

Comment: 3 years you've been looking? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vL7gAUV3w1E